# Xcode freezes on launch

Tags: xcode

I have a checked out a project from our SVN repository and every time I try to open it, it freezes. I have tried cleaning out the Autosave Information and locked the Saved Application State folders. cleaned and re-cleaned the derivedData and so on. 
The only things I didn't try are reinstalling XCode or creating a new user ... since I don't have the time to setup up everything right now. 
But if everything else fails I will have to do it.

Below is a screenshot ... as soon as I click anywhere in Xcode, it freezez with the spinner going on like a madman. Xcode version: 4.6.1 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it ... [Thanks to brian chan](http://birdchan.com/home/2013/03/21/xcode-keeps-freezing/)

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

put this in your terminal. It will disable autocomplete and jump to definition though

Comment: Because links can expire please could you update your answer with how you solved it. Thanks.

Comment: At least I can open the project ... but it's really nasty since the project I needed opened is massive.